# DataTables won't get redrawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I can't seem to refresh DataTable upon external dropdown change. What I'm trying to achieve is translate (HTML sourced) table header upon language selection, but `.draw()` method doesn't seem to get invoked. Any ideas as of how to fix that are appreciated.

```js
var lang = {en:['code','name','qty'], es:['codigo','nombre','cantidad'], fr:['code','prenom','quantite']};
var dataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
 sDom: 'ts',
  columns: [
   {data: 'code', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][0]},
    {data: 'name', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][1]},
    {data: 'qty', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][2]}
  ]
});

$('#lang').on('change', function(){
 dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<select id="lang">
  <option value="en">EN</option>
  <option value='es'>ES</option>
  <option value="fr">FR</option>
</select>
<table id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>qty</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Toyota Camry</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Ford Focus</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>KIA Sportage</td>
      <td>4</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it _is_ working, but nothing is updated so you don't see any difference in the table.  Put an alert() in the change event and see if that shows up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, it will fire an alarm, because I already tried that with `console.log('redraw')` and it throws the message upon language selection. On the other hand, it must have changed column titles as `$('lang').val()` has changed. So why it's not getting redrawn accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draw function only refreshes the datatable with newly provided sort and filters not if the columns change. Also, when the value on `lang` dropdown changes, it does not update the datatable because it datatable already been initialiazed. What you can do is, destroy the datatable on language change and reinitialize it with columns according to new language. 
You can also user `column().header()` function of datatable object to update the text of html labels.
I have updated your code to achieve this in the snippet below.

```js
  

              var lang = {en:['code','name','qty'], es:['codigo','nombre','cantidad'], fr:['code','prenom','quantite']};
      
      
          
        
    var datatable =datatable=$('#dataTable').DataTable({
              sDom: 'ts',
            columns: [
                {data: 'code', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][0]},
              {data: 'name', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][1]},
              {data: 'qty', title: lang[$('#lang').val()][2]}
            ]
          });
      
         
          $('#lang').on('change', function(){
             updateColumnLabels();
          });
  function updateColumnLabels(){
    $(datatable.column(0).header()).html(lang[$('#lang').val()][0]);
    $(datatable.column(1).header()).html(lang[$('#lang').val()][1]);
    $(datatable.column(2).header()).html(lang[$('#lang').val()][2]);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<select id="lang">
  <option value="en">EN</option>
  <option value='es'>ES</option>
  <option value="fr">FR</option>
</select>
<table id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>qty</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Toyota Camry</td>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Ford Focus</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>KIA Sportage</td>
      <td>4</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It obviously works, but isn't there some smarter way to redraw the table without destroying it completely and recreating anew? `.draw()` tutorial page doesn't say the table MUST be sorted or filtered in order to use the method, so, is it really mandatory? Besides, I might assume, your solution will likely reset any sorting/filtering upon language selection.

Comment: @user10842417 Yes destroying and redrawing the header is one way of achieving it but it will remove the sorting and filtering. However if you only want to update the column headers text, you can also use `column().header()` function of datatable object to get the header html element and then update its html. See my edit above.

Comment: p/s: It's probably safer to use `.text()` instead of `.html()` ;) also, looping through the header cells instead of selecting them individually by index will also take a lot of redundancy out of the code.

Comment: Updating column headers specifically without redrawing entire table perfectly suits this particular purpose and, I believe, should work even faster. But it still keeps me confused, why `.draw()` does not actually draw. However, I'm going to have to mark this answer as the best one (and the only :). Many thanks.